# Magento custom breadcrumbs translation not not working

Tags: magento

Hello how can i translate my custom breadcrumbs on shopping cart page.

My checkout.xml code here for display breadcrumbs on shopping cart page.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb" >
        <crumbName>home</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb" >
        <crumbName>Shopping Cart</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo><label>Shopping Cart</label><title>Shopping Cart</title></crumbInfo>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Above code output on shoping cart page.

```
Home / Shopping Cart
```

I nedd to translate above label and title.

How i can solve this issu.

I already added translation text in Mage_Checkout.csv.

```
"Shopping Cart","Carrinho De Compras"
```

But now working translation text how can it done ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify path to translatable item in arguments hiearchy. To do that, you add translate parameter in your action.

```
<action method="methodName" translate="foo">
    <foo>I will be translated by Core module</foo>
</action>
```

If you want to manage your translation from Mage_Checkout.csv, you need to specify the translator module.

```
<action method="methodName" translate="foo" module="checkout">
    <foo>I will be translated by Checkout module</foo>
</action>
```

But here is the trick: You are trying to translate an inner argument of crumbInfo. You need to use a dot seperator to make it happen. Also you can add multiple arguments to translate parameter by seperating them with space.

Here is the code for you;

```
<action method="addCrumb" module="checkout" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
    <crumbName>Shopping Cart</crumbName>
    <crumbInfo><label>Shopping Cart</label><title>Shopping Cart</title></crumbInfo>
</action>
```

Comment: I have getting solution by below my answer, is also same as your answer. Realy great solution @muhammedv. Thanks.

Comment: Best solution is always the one you find yourself :) Have a nice day @user3793635

Answer (score 2):

It is completed by this code

```
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
        <crumbName>home</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
    </action>
    <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
        <crumbName>Shopping Cart</crumbName>
        <crumbInfo><label>Shopping Cart</label><title>Shopping Cart</title></crumbInfo>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

[Get refrence from by this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24270/translation-doesnt-work-on-breadcrumbs-added-by-xml)